# What does cloning a GitHub repository mean?

Tags: swift, xcode, git, github, git-clone

I am trying to integrate Facebook with my app. I read this on [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/):

> 1. Install [XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)
> 2. Install [Git](https://git-scm.com/)
> 3. Clone the GitHub repository with this command:
>      `git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git`

I have installed XCode and Git.

What does it mean to <kbd>clone</kbd> a GitHub repository and how can I do that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To clone a repository means to duplicate and download everything in the repository.

You are on a Mac, so launch Terminal, create a folder and type this command:

```sh
git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git
```

It will duplicate and download the entire repository.

Comment: git downloads it but where will it be located?

Comment: in the folder that you create as Pierre mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

Cloning a git repository means that you create a local copy of the code provided by developer. You can simply do it with a command line:

```
git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git .
```

and you'll have the code in the `facebook-ios-sdk` directory.

Answer (score 4):

Cloning a git repository is basically downloading a code base to your own machine, so you can use, edit... this code base.

For doing it is as easy as creating a folder where you want to store this code, and then from the terminal execute from this folder:

```
git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git .
```

Comment: So how does Terminal know where you want this repository to go to? I believe your instruction is missing something crucial. There has to be a step between creating a folder and cloning the repository.

Comment: You need to get Terminal into the right directory before hand.

Answer (score 3):

Cloning a repository means that you're downloading a copy of the source code from source control.  To use the iOS SDK you have to download the code from GitHub (ie- clone the iOS SDK repository).

Type

```
git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git [path to where you want to save sdk]
```

from a shell / command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Cloning basically means you want to get a local copy of the code present in the repository.
After cloning you can then do whatever changes you like in the code and then you can pull the changes back to the repository

Answer (score 0):

clone the repo

Cloning  = means copying

Repo  = is short form of Repository which is the complete files of the project

Create a folder, Open terminal and take the path into that folder where you want to save the repo, and then run this command

```
git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git
```

This command will download all the files to that folder

Welcome in Advance