# Python+Git on for remote repository

Tags: python, git, pull

Can any one tell me how I can **pull** data from remote repository (**custom branch**) with Python?
Im currently using **GitPython**...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the python [dulwich](http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/) package.

Check out this question for some direction:
[Programmatically `git checkout .` with dulwich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640546/programmatically-git-checkout-with-dulwich)

Answer (score 1):

To [*clone* a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5143155/1240268).

```
repo = Repo.clone_from("path/of/repo/to/pull", "path/of/clone")
```

This function is described more precisely in the [docs](http://packages.python.org/GitPython/0.3.2/reference.html#git.repo.base.Repo.clone_from).

.

In order to **pull** the latest, you should use the [pull GitPython command](http://packages.python.org/GitPython/0.3.2/reference.html#git.remote.Remote.pull):

```
repo.pull()
```

*by default this should use the paths specified on instantiation as `<src>:<dst>`.*

Comment: I have already cloned repo in my local directory... all I wan to do is:
*git pull origin turbo_branch*

not in console but with GitPython